# SQL Server dynamic SQL to query on sys tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have written a stored procedure that calculates table statistics using the `sys` tables. I realize there are reports in SSMS that do this for you, however, I'm wanting additional information. It seems like I'm forced to use dynamic SQL to make this happen, but it seems slow and clunky. My stored procedure works, but I was curious there a more efficient way to write the query, maybe even without dynamic SQL?

```
DECLARE @my_cursor CURSOR, 
        @sql nvarchar(250), @table_name nvarchar(100),
        @days_loaded int, @row_count int, @row_count_per_day int, 
        @used_mb numeric(36,2), @used_mb_per_day numeric(36,2),
        @first_date_loaded date, @last_date_loaded date, 
        @expected_first_date date, @gaps_exist nvarchar(1)

-- Delete temp table #tables in case the stored procedure is ran twice in the same session
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tables', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #tables

-- Select all the tables and stats from the dallas schema into a temp table
SELECT 
    s.name + '.' + t.name AS table_name,
    p.rows AS row_count,
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(a.used_pages) / 128.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS used_mb
INTO
    #tables
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions AS p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units AS a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    s.name = 'dallas'
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows

-- Add some additional fields in the temp table to be used for population in loop below
ALTER TABLE #tables ADD days_loaded INT NULL
ALTER TABLE #tables ADD used_mb_per_day numeric(36,2) NULL
ALTER TABLE #tables ADD row_count_per_day INT NULL
ALTER TABLE #tables ADD first_date_loaded DATE NULL
ALTER TABLE #tables ADD expected_first_date DATE NULL
ALTER TABLE #tables ADD gaps_exist nvarchar(1) NULL

-- Loop through each table in dallas schema
BEGIN
    SET @my_cursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name, row_count, used_mb FROM #tables

    OPEN @my_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM @my_cursor INTO @table_name, @row_count, @used_mb

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Calculate first date that was loaded to see history of how far back table goes
        SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 1 @first_date_loaded = CONVERT(date,Min(data_load_timestamp)) FROM ' + @table_name
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@first_date_loaded date OUTPUT', @first_date_loaded=@first_date_loaded OUTPUT

        -- Calculate last date that was loaded to offset expected first date if needed (data that is loaded day of instead of day before)
        SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 1 @last_date_loaded = CONVERT(date,Max(data_load_timestamp)) FROM ' + @table_name
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@last_date_loaded date OUTPUT', @last_date_loaded=@last_date_loaded OUTPUT

        -- Calculate days loaded by retrieving count of distinct dates in table
        SET @sql = N'SELECT @days_loaded=COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(date, data_load_timestamp) AS data_load_date FROM ' + @table_name + ') tt'
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@days_loaded int OUTPUT', @days_loaded=@days_loaded OUTPUT
        IF @days_loaded <> 0
            BEGIN
                SET @row_count_per_day = @row_count / @days_loaded
                SET @used_mb_per_day = @used_mb / @days_loaded
                SET @expected_first_date = DATEADD(d,@days_loaded * -1,GETDATE())
                IF @last_date_loaded = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) SET @expected_first_date = DATEADD(d,1,@expected_first_date)
                IF @first_date_loaded = @expected_first_date
                    SET @gaps_exist = 'N'
                ELSE
                    SET @gaps_exist = 'Y'
            END

        -- Update temp table with additional fields that were calculated
        SET @sql = N'UPDATE #tables SET days_loaded=' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@days_loaded) + 
                   ', row_count_per_day=' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @row_count_per_day) +
                   ', used_mb_per_day=' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@used_mb_per_day) + ', first_date_loaded=''' +
                   CONVERT(nvarchar,@first_date_loaded) + ''', expected_first_date=''' +
                   CONVERT(nvarchar,@expected_first_date) + ''', gaps_exist=''' + @gaps_exist + ''' WHERE table_name=''' + @table_name + ''''
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
        FETCH NEXT FROM @my_cursor INTO @table_name, @row_count, @used_mb
    END
    CLOSE @my_cursor
    DEALLOCATE @my_cursor
END
-- Final return showing results from temp table sorted by largest utilization first
SELECT * FROM #tables ORDER BY used_mb DESC
```

Comment: I need to know how many days of data are in each table

Comment: Switching from a cursor for a dataset method and running the how batch in one go will *probably* provide an improvement.

Comment: I'm running SQL on each table, how would I write it in such a way where I don't have to iterate through each row?

Comment: The "normal" method is by using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`.There's lots of examples our there on how to use it on delimited data. In this case, however, your "delimiter" is a Line Break (and Carriage Return).

Comment: You could use [sys.db_db_stats_properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-properties-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and  [sys.dm_db_stats_histogram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-histogram-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [sys.dm_db_incremental_stats_properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-incremental-stats-properties-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: In the links above, you'll see examples with `CROSS APPLY` on the `sys.stats` table to get the `object_id` and `stats_id` for the function